# UML diagram libraries with Vue3 support

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Can you please recommend any UML diagram libraries which supports Vue3? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10+ JavaScript libraries to including `vuejs` draw your own diagrams (2020 edition)

[UML library](https://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).